# Root username is different to admin username

Tags: permissions, root

I have somehow changed my root username which seems to have caused my system to disallow me to mount USB, CDROM.

My normal username is jenchris, however if I type:

su root (and enter the password)

then it shows **root@jenchris-H55M-UD2H:/home/jenchris#** (PLEASE NOTE THE HASH AT THE END OF THE USERNAME!)

I think I accidentally hit the hash key at some point whilst typing my username....

This is causing huge problems as I have lost lots of permissions, eg cannot mount USB drives:

---

If I plug in my USB drive, it appears under 'devices', but if I click on it, I get:

Unable to access SAMSUNG, Not authorized to perform operation

Output of ls -l /media is

```
total 4
drwxr-x---+ 2 root root 4096 Nov  2 21:51 jenchris
```

I also do not have the privileges to: Run software centre or software updater; Press the GUI shut down or restart buttons; Unlock my account in the 'settings - user accounts' section (padlock is greyed out).

Answer (score 0):

No `#` is just an indication that you are in root mode.

`root@jenchris-H55M-UD2H:` - Here `root` is the user name, `jenchris-H55M-UD2H` is the machine name. Rest are just a path.

In ubuntu by default the root account is disabled. First user (the name you given at time installation) is given a special permission to do root user's job. It is called a `sudoers` account.

I think you accidentally (or without knowing) removed your account from sudo list and enabled root account.

To solve this you can run the following

from root terminal (like above terminal with #)

`adduser <username> sudo`  - username should be your default user name. (most probably jenchris)

Now logout & log back in, you should be able to mount usb & do the other things.

Disable root account

`sudo passwd -dl root`

More information about sudo , root with their cons & pros → https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Comment: Thanks - I have done the steps you suggested, unfortunately I still cannot mount USB/CDROM - in 'settings - user accounts' my account is locked even though it says I am administrator. Any ideas?

Comment: mounting could be another problem with permission, but can you run `sudo nautilus` using your own password (not root's)? does the drive get mounted with this nautilus window?

Comment: no
(nautilus:26946): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 1.4.0

(nautilus:26946): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/jenchris/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.

Comment: when I run sudo nautilus, I get the error message described above, and a window opens - but my USB drive is not found under 'devices' and I still get the error message 'not authorized to perform operation' when I plug it in. Any suggestions?

Comment: No the above is not an error message, it is warning message. NOt a problem. Reboot your system once, try plugging in the device & click on it for mounting. Edit your question and include the exact error message, and output of `ls -l /media`

Comment: Try running `sudo chown -R jenchris:jenchris /media`. But I think you already messed with some critical permission issue (software center is not opening either).If you don't remember what you did, I would recommend a re installation.